# import csv file into Mysql Database using python

Tags: python, mysql, csv

This is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python 
import MySQLdb
import csv

db = MySQLdb.connect(host="host", # The Host
                     user="username", # username
                     passwd="pwd", # password
                     db="databasename") # name of the data base

sqlLoadData = 'LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "csv?_file_name.csv" INTO TABLE tablename '   
sqlLoadData += 'FIELDS TERMINATED BY "," LINES TERMINATED BY "\n"'     
sqlLoadData += 'IGNORE 1 LINES'     
sqlLoadData += 'ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY "\\" '

try:
    curs = db.cursor()   
    curs.execute(sqlLoadData)    
    resultSet = curs.fetchall()    
except StandardError, e:    
    print e    
    db.rollback()
    db.close()
```

I recieve the error Message : You have an error in your SQL Syntax; chekc the manual that correcpond to your Mysql Server.

When I remove the part `sqlLoadData += 'ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY "\\" '` everything work perfect. I used the last part just to remove the quote from the values.

I also tried:

> cursor = mydb.cursor()
>
> reader = csv.reader(open('Cumulative.csv', 'rb'))
>
> reader.next() for row in reader[1:]:
>       cursor.execute('INSERT INTO Cumulative (C1, C2, C3, C4, C5, C6) VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)', row)
>    cursor.commit()

close the connection to the database.

> cursor.close()

I want just to remove the quote so the integer field will support the data. so with quote "1" will be considered as a String instead of integer

Can Anyone please help me to understand this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

looks like you forgot to terminate the preceding line with a space or newline character. Thi sis causing a syntax error when the parser tries to understand `LINESENCLOSED` which obviously isn't a keyword.

```
 sqlLoadData += 'IGNORE 1 LINES \n'
 sqlLoadData += ''ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY "\" ''
```

As a rule of thumb: when you're debugging, and you're able to fix you're code by removing a line, don't rule out the line *immediately above*

EDIT: Modified the quotes around the second line. I think it was breaking in the "enclosed by" statement.

Comment: That fixed the Mysql Query, but that gave me an error Unexpected Character after line continuation character { '  }

Comment: Made a change, try it now. (encapsulate the whole string by an extra set of single quotes)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick replay!! Still Same Error Message.

Comment: The problem is that python thinks that you are terminating your string prematurely. The error message means the interpreter is reading the backslash as a "line continuation" character. Try encapsulating this line using different combinations of single and double quotes.

Comment: Thank you so much David, I made some changes and I tried a new way but no luck.

Answer (score 2):

After 2 days worth of research I found the answer:

```
!/usr/bin/python  
import MySQLdb 
import csv

db = MySQLdb.connect(host="host", # The Host
                      user="username", # username
                      passwd="pwd", # password
                      db="databasename") # name of the data base

 cursor = connection.cursor() 
 Query = """ LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'usrl to csv file' INTO TABLE
 table_nameFIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED
 BY '"' Lines terminated by '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES """

cursor.execute(Query)   
connection.commit()   
cursor.close()
```

hope it will help somebody out there.

Comment: It would be nice if you explain why the error occurred and how you solved it.

Comment: I can explain the error if you want. He solved the error be encapsulating all of his text in triple quotes instead of building it up peicewise, which is really much much better. His original error, which I had missed as well, was that he only terminated his first and fourth line with a white space character, but his second and third lines needed them as well. I thoguht his second line had a new line character at the end, but it actually just had a new line character contained in a command "lines terminated by" command.

Answer (score 2):

After days and hours of searching the internet and running into all sort of errors and warnings, this worked perfectly. I hope this saves someone some time

```
import MySQLdb
import os
import string

db = MySQLdb.connect (host="host",
    user="user",
    passwd="pwd",
    db="database_name",
    local_infile = 1) #Grants permission to write to db from an input file. Without this you get sql Error: (1148, 'The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version')

print "\nConnection to DB established\n"

#The statement 'IGNORE 1 LINES' below makes the Python script ignore first line on csv file
#You can execute the sql below on the mysql bash to test if it works
sqlLoadData = """load data local infile 'file.csv' into table table_name FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES;"""

try:
    curs = db.cursor()   
    curs.execute(sqlLoadData)
    db.commit()   
    print "SQL execution complete"   
    resultSet = curs.fetchall()   
except StandardError, e:    
    print "Error incurred: ", e    
    db.rollback()
    db.close()

print "Data loading complete.\n"
```

Thanks, I hope this helps :)